# Return multiple items from the function in python

Tags: python

```
def outside_func(name = 'pink'):
    def inside_func():
        return "This is inside function"
    def inside_func2():
        return "This is inside function 2 "
    return inside_func,inside_func2
```

Here I call the function

```
my_func = outside_func()
print(my_func())
```

I am getting an error like :

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [40], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 funccc()

TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

I want to print the return statement.

Comment: `outside_func` returns a tuple of functions, you need to choose which one to call, ie `outside_func()[0]()`

Comment: You're returning a *tuple of functions*. You need to call each individually, not the tuple as a whole: `my_func[0]()`…

Comment: Thank you .
for i in range(len(my_func)):
    print(my_func[i]())

Comment: Or just `for f in my_func: print(f())`. Don't unnecessarily iterate over iterables using `range`.

Answer (score 0):

You are retuning a `tuple` that has two functions. So to call the first function you need to access it via its index. i.e.

```
print(outside_func()[0]()) # "This is inside function"
```

Same for the other one..

```
print(outside_func()[1]()) # "This is inside function 2 "
```

Or you can unpack the tuple to variables, e.g.

```
(f1, f2) = outside_func()

print(f1()) # "This is inside function"

print(f2()) # "This is inside function 2 "
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to return multiple objects, you can just separate them with commas as you did.

```
def demo_func():
    x = "X"
    y = "Y"
    return x, y

print( demo_func() )
```

But in your current code, you try to return the functions themselves.
You would have to write

```
return inside_func() ,inside_func2()
```

I'm not sure about passing on multiple functions in python if that's what you're looking for. Maybe lists?

Answer (score -1):

```
my_func[0:2]
```

This will print both inner functions together.

Comment: I tried this but it is providing .(<function __main__.outside_func.<locals>.inside_func()>,
 <function __main__.outside_func.<locals>.inside_func2()>)